# Merge 2 dataframes and create a list of values relative to a few columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Given two dataframes (that can contain multiple rows with same id):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
userid,a,b,c,email_work
1,0,0,0,a@a.com
2,0,0,0,b@b.com
3,0,0,0,c@c.com
4,0,0,0,d@d.com
4,0,0,0,e@e.com"""))

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
id,A,B,email_personal,email_other
2,0,0,b@b.com,f@f.com
4,0,0,g@g.com"""))
```

I'd like to get a list (or better: a set) of all email addresses for each user:

```
userid,emails
1,[a@a.com]
2,[b@b.com, f@f.com]
3,[c@c.com]
4,[d@d.com, e@e.com, g@g.com]
```

(I tried various things with `merge`, `join`, `concatenate` but without success, I don't have a clear view of a pythonic solution.)

**How to merge 2 dataframes and create a list/set of values relative to a few columns (here `email_work`, `email_personal`, `email_other`)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is create `Series` with `id` for index in both `DataFrame`s - in first by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and in second is necessary select all only `email` columns by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and remove second level by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
s1 = df1.set_index('userid')['email_work']
s2 = df2.set_index('id').filter(like='email').stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

Last join togehter by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and aggregate by index (level=0) expected `set`s, last convert `Series` to `2 columns DataFrame` by [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html) and [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = (pd.concat([s1, s2])
        .groupby(level=0)
        .agg(set)
        .rename_axis('userid')
        .reset_index(name='emails'))
print (df)
   userid                       emails
0       1                    {a@a.com}
1       2           {b@b.com, f@f.com}
2       3                    {c@c.com}
3       4  {g@g.com, d@d.com, e@e.com}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rename the `id` to `userid` to make the userid column same name , then stack the columns having the work `email` using [`df.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and [`df.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)and name them `email_work` , then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with inner join and groupby + aggregate as set to remove duplicate values

```
m = (df2.set_index('id').filter(like='email').rename_axis('userid')
        .stack().reset_index(name='email_work'))

out = (pd.concat((df1,m),join='inner').groupby('userid')['email_work'].agg(set)
      .reset_index())
```

---

```
print(out)

   userid                   email_work
0       1                    {a@a.com}
1       2           {b@b.com, f@f.com}
2       3                    {c@c.com}
3       4  {d@d.com, g@g.com, e@e.com}
```

---

```
print(m)

   userid         level_1 email_work
0       2  email_personal    b@b.com
1       2     email_other    f@f.com
2       4  email_personal    g@g.com
```

Comment: PS: the last `.reset_index()` is not really necessary, is it?

Comment: @Basj only if you are okay to keep userid as index :) else it is required if you want as column , and thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just an addendum to help the understanding of the different steps of @jezrael's solution:

```
s1 = df1.set_index('userid')['email_work']
print("s1::\n", s1)
print("df2::\n", df2)
print("filter::\n",     df2.set_index('id').filter(like='email'))
print("stack::\n",      df2.set_index('id').filter(like='email').stack())
print("resetindex::\n", df2.set_index('id').filter(like='email').stack().reset_index(level=1))
s2 =                    df2.set_index('id').filter(like='email').stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
print('drop=True::\n', s2)
print('agg::\n',        pd.concat([s1, s2]).groupby(level=0).agg(set))
print('renameaxis::\n', pd.concat([s1, s2]).groupby(level=0).agg(set).rename_axis('userid'))                             # Set the name of the axis for the index or columns.
print('resetindex::\n', pd.concat([s1, s2]).groupby(level=0).agg(set).rename_axis('userid').reset_index(name='emails'))  # This is useful when the index needs to be treated as a column, or when the index is meaningless and needs to be reset to the default before another operation.
```

Same with @anky's answer:

```
print('renameaxis::\n', df2.set_index('id').filter(like='email').rename_axis('userid'))
print('stack::\n',      df2.set_index('id').filter(like='email').rename_axis('userid').stack())
m =   df2.set_index('id').filter(like='email').rename_axis('userid').stack().reset_index(name='email_work')
print('resetindex::\n', m)
print('concat::\n',     pd.concat((df1, m), join='inner'))
print('agg::\n',        pd.concat((df1, m), join='inner').groupby('userid')['email_work'].agg(set))
print('resetindex::\n', pd.concat((df1, m), join='inner').groupby('userid')['email_work'].agg(set).reset_index())
```